# Array Checkbox validation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to validate an Array checkbox using Jquery, but i dont know how validate the checkbox using jquery... this is my code

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='0' id='checkboxvar[]'>L</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='1' id='checkboxvar[]'>M</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='2' id='checkboxvar[]'>Mi</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='3' id='checkboxvar[]'>J</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='4' id='checkboxvar[]'>V</label>
</div>

<script>
 function validate() {
        if($("#checkboxvar").is(':checked')) {
            alert("actived");
        } else {
            alert("No actived");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Start by not using the same ID for all the elements. Then learn about [event handlers](https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/)

Comment: Do you want to be alerted "Activated" if all the checkboxes are checked?

Comment: just i want validate if anyone checkbox is actived, for proced to save

Comment: @adeneo how you say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all remove the id duplication. Id should be unique  per page.

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/bdjue21w/

If you want to check which checkbox is checked on validate you can just apply common class to all of them and then traverse over it and check if any one of them is checked.

Like below

```
 function validate() {
    $(".checkboxvar").each(function(index){
       if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert("checked element value : " + + $(this).val());
       } else{
       alert("unchecked element value: " + $(this).val());
       }
 });
 }
```

Assuming HTML to be like this :

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='0' class='checkboxvar'>L</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='1' class='checkboxvar'>M</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='2' class='checkboxvar'>Mi</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='3' class='checkboxvar'>J</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvar[]' value='4' class='checkboxvar'>V</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
You can validate like below:

function validate(){
    if ($('input[name^=checkboxvar]:checked').length <= 0) {
        alert("Not active");
    }else{
        alert("active");
    }
}
```

Comment: very useful when we use checkbox names with array